# PFFacebookUtils - Hiding progress HUD after reauthorizeUser

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform

In my iOS app, the following code logs a user in using Facebook:

```
- (IBAction)facebookAuthButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    [PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:@[@"basic_info", @"user_about_me"] block:^(PFUser *appUser, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Login succeeded");//todo: other app logic
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
        if (appUser) {
            [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
            [PFFacebookUtils reauthorizeUser:[PFUser currentUser] withPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_stream"] audience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
                NSLog(@"Reauthorize succeeded");//todo: other app logic
            }];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Reauthorize failed");//todo: other app logic
            //todo show alert
        }
    }];
}
```

I see `Login succeeded` in the console, then the webpage asking me for authorization appears. After I click OK, the app appears again with the progress hud showing and it never disappears.
I never see "Reauthorize succeeded" or "Reauthorize failed" in console.

Is that block passed to reauthorize being called on a different thread than the thread the reauthorize call was made in i.e. the main thread?

**Update**
I tried following and it still doesn't work. Only `Login succeeded` is printed on console. My breakpoint placed inside the block never reaches.

```
- (IBAction)facebookAuthButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    [PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:@[@"basic_info", @"user_about_me"] block:^(PFUser *appUser, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Login succeeded");//todo: other app logic
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
        if (appUser) {
            [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
            //todo the user may decide not to authorize the app to post on their behalf. We need to handle this. During sharing for instance we may have to let the user know that they cant share since they haven't authorized the app andgive them option to authorize.
            [PFFacebookUtils reauthorizeUser:[PFUser currentUser] withPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_stream"] audience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends block: ^ (BOOL succeeded, NSError *error){
//             [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(facebookAuthorizationCompleted) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
                NSLog(@"Reauthorize finished");
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    NSLog(@"In dispatch");
                });
            }];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Login failed");//todo: other app logic
            //todo show alert
        }
    }];
}
```

**Update 2**
I noticed following in the console:

2014-02-21 09:59:58.679 CrossPlex[13839:740b] Can't endBackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier b, or it may have already been ended. Break in UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError() to debug.

Seems like it would be related to the app transferring control to Safari and then Safari transferring back control to the app during the reauthorize process.

Comment: I haven't found a way to test this yet, but I think what is happening is that the block is called only if reauthorization took place. If the app had already been granted appropriate permissions, indicated by 'You have already authorized this app' message on the webpage that is opened, the block is not called. I will post an answer as soon as a I find a way to revoke the authorization and then see if the block is called.